# Logstash multiline not grouping the messages

Tags: elasticsearch, multiline, logstash

I followed logstash documentation about [multiline](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/filters/multiline) and tried to experiment it with a basic stdin & stdout configuration, but it does not seem to work. The tag "multiline" is added on the next messages, but they end as separate entries with a "_grokparsefailure" tag.

What am I missing?

Edit: as a reference I was using a [stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/smougenot/3182192) multiline filter.

Comment: Can you provide your configuration file?

Comment: you can reproduce the problem with any working configuration. Just wait a few seconds between the "normal" message and the first multiline input and the grouping will not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Ok that one was a bit tricky, so I thought it might be appreciated if I gave here the solution. I found it in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/Xx9SxMxM60s): multiline triggers only if the next lines come quickly (within 1~2 second). So when experimenting, if you take your time copying and pasting each line you will think it doesn't work while it actually does.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the example mentioned in the [blog](http://blog.lanyonm.org/articles/2014/01/12/logstash-multiline-tomcat-log-parsing.html). I successfully implemented multiline with this approach.

For more clarification, please provide your config along with sample input message.

Answer (score 0):

This is my configuration. I use the example from Logstash [multiline](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/filters/multiline)

```
input {
    stdin {
    }
}

filter {
    multiline {
       # Grok pattern names are valid! :)
       pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
       negate => true
       what => previous
    }
}


output {
    stdout {debug => true}
}
```

With this logs, The multiline function is work on me.

```
2014-02-24 10:00:01  abcde
1qaz
2014-01-01 11:11:11
2wsx
```

I enter the logs one by one and wait for 1 minute between each line. So, I didn't have meet your problem. Please verify your configuration.

Comment: To be honnest I did not expected getting any replies since I have been asking a lot recently and never getting any help and I thought it would be the same this time, so I only came to give my solution for the uncertain probability someone would find it helpful. But I will take a deeper look when I get some time